# Can JavaPairRDD ever take an Array instead of a Tuple2 in Spark Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, tuples, java-pair-rdd

I reading the "Learning Spark" book and for example 5-14, I noticed that a `JavaPairRDD<String[]>` was declared. I'm pretty sure that JavaPairRDD's can only take Tuple2s (i.e. for Key and Value) but I wasn't sure if there was some weird implicit conversion going on from String[] to Tuple2 somehow.

I can't find any other examples of this online except for this exact example.

Here's a [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=tOptBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT117&lpg=PT117&dq=JavaPairRDD%3CString%5B%5D%3E%20csvData&source=bl&ots=EBOouAwV-E&sig=I0wCy5kdMgCNacXeiVqNsx4hjeE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwzfbw6OfaAhVl4IMKHU29B2cQ6AEIRzAC#v=onepage&q&f=false) to the page in the book.

Comment: It cannot. JavaPairRDD is parameterized with two types, and the map method on the right hand side doesn't return JavaPairRDD. It is clearly a mistake in print.

Comment: formatting issues

Comment: Ah yeah I didn't even consider the method on the right hand side! Thanks!